# How to change the next question based on the previous response on Slack Forms?

Tags: automation, workflow, slack

I am trying to create a slack workflow with a form. A shortcut will trigger it and once someone clicks on the shortcut a form will pop up to be filled.
Slack's form builder is super simple, so I cannot create some advanced stuff. What I want to do:

- The first question is related to the type of the question
- Based on the answer to the first question, I want to ask different questions.

How can I build that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals aren't present within Workflow Builder at the moment!

Comment: Do you know any workaround for that?